Identify a movie about some very surreal settings, a king with a ducttape crown and spiders with a eyeballs as bodies
About 3-4 years ago, when I was pretty sleep deprived, I watched a movie that was set in a very surreal landscape.
Of what I can remember there was a lot of fog, and there were people standing in front of a giant bridge. I can recall only one of those people, and he was a king of some sort, he wore a crown made of duct-tape like material.
In another shot I saw walking eyeballs, which had a spider-like appearance. 
Throughout the movie, there were some more of those weird 'animals' passing by etc, but unfortunately I can not recall any more details about those 'animals'.
The setting was very grey with a lot of accented vibrant colors, and was played by real humans in front of a green screen, seen the nature of the environment. 
The movie was, if I recall correctly, originally in English, but was re-dubbed in Dutch.
I have been breaking my head to find this movie for the last few days, to find out what I was watching, as it didn't make very much sense to me at the time.

For the people downvoting me, please share why you do so

Because a lot of people don't like identification questions and a high bar is set by them on their detail and quality.  For help on information that might help identification please see the 'Identify-This-X' section of the following page: https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Hi and welcome to M&TV. Didn't DV because your Q isn't bad and quite answerable, but some more details might certainly help, like: What was the movie's approximate year\decade of release? Was it animated? CG? Live action? Was it in color? Do you remember any other characters, scenes or plot lines, however vaguely?

I don't think it was bad either btw, and although I'm not a personal fan of them don't like the auto-downvoting of reasonably good examples like this.

Sounds like MirrorMask from 2005, written by Neil Gaiman.

In a fantasy world of opposing kingdoms, a 15-year-old girl named Helena who works at the family circus with her father and mother, who wishes--quite ironically--that she could run away from the circus and join 'real life'. But such is not to be the case, as she finds herself on a strange journey into the Dark Lands, a fantastic landscape filled with giants, Monkeybirds and dangerous sphinxes. She must find the fabled MirrorMask in order to save the kingdom and get back home.

It's all a surreal green-screen spectacle full of the weird creatures you described.
The eyeball spiders:

The 'king' with a weird ducttape-like crown and mask:

The bridge:

